# How to sample a mip level in glsl using textureLod?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, sampling

How do I go about sampling a mip level in glsl using textureLod()?

From what I know, mipmap LOD can **only** be "*explicitly*" accessed through the vertex shader (although not sure if it's supported in version 420, as most of the documentation is outdated). Second, you need to define the mipmap level-of-detail by setting texture parameters, such as **GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL** and **GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL**.

In my code, I define these texture parameters after calling **glCompressedTexImage2D**:

```
glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, min_filter);
glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mag_filter);
glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 9);
glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrap_s);
glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrap_t);
```

Next, I use this code for each binding each texture sample (types such as albedo map ect):

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);    // Set active texture type
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);   // Bind the texture object
```

Finally, here is my shader code:

Vertex:

```
#version 420 core

out vec3 _texcoord;
out vec4 _albedo_lod;

uniform sampler2D albedo;   // Albedo and specular map

void main()
{
    _texcoord = texcoord;
    _albedo_lod = textureLod(albedo, vec2(_texcoord.st), 2.0);
}
```

With the attaching fragment:

```
#version 420 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 gAlbedo;  // Albedo texel colour

in vec3 _texcoord;
in vec4 _albedo_lod;

void main()
{
    gAlbedo = _albedo_lod;  // Assign albedo
}
```

Now for some reason, **no matter** what LOD value I input, the result always resorts to this:

[image]
Which seems to be the very last mip level (despite what value I input). Bearing in mind I'm packing 10 mip levels as a **.dds** file. When however I manually set the base mip level via the texture parameter **GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL**, it works.

So all in all, Why won't it sample the correct mip level in glsl using textureLod? Is this somewhat deprecated in version 420?

**EDIT:** Here is the code for loading the dds file:

```
// This function imports a dds file and returns the dds data as a struct
inline GLuint LoadDds(std::vector<std::string> file, size_t &img_width, size_t &img_height, size_t &num_mips, GLvoid* data, GLint wrap_s, GLint wrap_t, GLint min_filter, GLint mag_filter, size_t texture_type, bool anistropic_filtering)
{

    // Create one OpenGL texture
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    // "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
    glBindTexture(texture_type, textureID);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++)  // For each image...
    {
        FILE *fp;

        unsigned char header[124];
        unsigned int height;
        unsigned int width;
        unsigned int linearSize;
        unsigned int mipMapCount;
        unsigned int fourCC;
        unsigned int components;
        unsigned int format;
        unsigned int bufsize;
        unsigned char* buffer;


        /* try to open the file */
        errno_t err;
        err = fopen_s(&fp, file[i].c_str(), "rb");
        if (fp == NULL)
            return 0;

        /* verify the type of file */
        char filecode[4];
        fread(filecode, 1, 4, fp);
        if (strncmp(filecode, "DDS ", 4) != 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }

        /* get the surface desc */
        fread(&header, 124, 1, fp);

        height = *(unsigned int*)&(header[8]);
        width = *(unsigned int*)&(header[12]);
        linearSize = *(unsigned int*)&(header[16]);
        mipMapCount = *(unsigned int*)&(header[24]);
        fourCC = *(unsigned int*)&(header[80]);
        bufsize = mipMapCount > 1 ? linearSize * 2 : linearSize;
        buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(unsigned char));

        fread(buffer, 1, bufsize, fp);

        /* close the file pointer */
        fclose(fp);

        components = (fourCC == FOURCC_DXT1) ? 3 : 4;
        switch (fourCC)
        {
        case FOURCC_DXT1:
            format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT;
            break;
        case FOURCC_DXT3:
            format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT;
            break;
        case FOURCC_DXT5:
            format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT;
            break;
        default:
            free(buffer);
            return 0;
        }

        unsigned int blockSize = (format == GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT) ? 8 : 16;

        unsigned int offset = 0;
        for (unsigned int level = 0; level < mipMapCount && (width || height); ++level)
        {
            unsigned int size = ((width + 3) / 4) * ((height + 3) / 4) * blockSize;
            glCompressedTexImage2D(texture_type != GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP ? GL_TEXTURE_2D : GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, level, format, width, height,
                0, size, buffer + offset);

            if ((level < 1) && (i < 1))     // Only assign input variable values from first image
            {
                img_width = width;  // Assign texture width
                img_height = height;    // Assign texture height
                data = buffer;  // Assign buffer data
                num_mips = mipMapCount;     // Assign number of mips
            }

            offset += size;
            width /= 2;
            height /= 2;
        }

        if (anistropic_filtering)   // If anistropic_filtering is true...
        {
            GLfloat f_largest;  // A contianer for storing the amount of texels in view for anistropic filtering
            glGetFloatv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, &f_largest);     // Query the amount of texels for calculation
            glTexParameterf(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, f_largest);    // Apply filter to texture
        }

        if (!mipMapCount)
            glGenerateMipmap(texture_type); // Generate mipmap

        free(buffer);   // Free buffers from memory
    }

    // Parameters
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, min_filter);
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mag_filter);
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 9);
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrap_s);
    glTexParameteri(texture_type, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrap_t);

    // Set additional cubemap parameters
    if (texture_type == GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, wrap_s);

    return textureID;   // Return texture id
}
```

And here is an image of each mipmap level being generated using NVIDIA's dds plugin:

[image]

Comment: `textureLod` is not deprecated for OpenGL 4. You also don't really need to set `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` and `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` unless you want to force OpenGL to use a subset of your existing mipmaps. The default values of `1000` and `0` should be fine. What leads you to believe your code is always sampling LOD 9 regardless of what value you give to `textureLod`?

Comment: Please, show the code where you upload or generate each mip map level.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I've uploaded the entire dds loader code ^ :) Thanks.

Comment: Fibbles - thanks for shedding some light on this subject. Basically the aim is to use each LOD value as a roughness step for cubemap convolution, and therefore having 10 levels will allow 1 for every 0.1 R. TextureLod is the only way to get access to the mips in real-time - although as you can see, the results seen to be using one of the very last levels due to it's low-level trilinear quality. Thanks.

Comment: (I'm interested to know about the actual benefit of swapping texture samplers for interpolators, have you tried profiling it? :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you sample per vertex this seems to be exactly the expected behavior.

You say the mip level parameter has no influence, but from what I can see the difference should only be noticeable once the pixel density goes under the vertex density and values starts averaging out. This might however never happen if you don't store the entire mipchain, since the lowest resolution might still have enough definition (I can't really tell from the screen capture, and I can only guess the model's tesselation).

Since you're generating the mipchain manually though you could easily test out with different flat colors for each level and see if they're indeed properly fetched (and actually if you're unsure about the importer it might be worth it to try it out in the pixel shader as well first).